# I am new to blender and I am trying a fluid sim but its stuck at 0%

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I don't know if I am doing it right or not but it's stuck at zero.  The fluid quality is at 125 and pretty choppy.  I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or not but it's stuck at zero.  I would add a project file but I don't know how to.  I've tried resizing the objects or changing the resolution. Thanks for any responses

Comment: Do you mean you can't bake the sim?

Comment: I've decided to try blender 2.90 instead but I have run into another issue.  The fluid goes straight through the imported obstacles.  But I can bake the fluid now.  I will try to add the blender file.